# Can I specify content for index.html in markdown?

Tags: pelican

For articles and pages I've got `article` and `page` objects available and I can use them to get my content on the website like `{{ page.title }}`. How to reference the `index.md` file in `index.html` template? Let's say:

index.md

```
Title: MyProject
Header: This is my first Pelican project
```

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<p>{{ page.Title }}</p>
<p>{{ page.Header }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```